# How scroll trigger move to next block function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why when I scroll, the window can't scroll to the next block? Does it cause from `scrollTop: '#' + $('.is-current').next().attr('id')`? Also I have tried use `offset().top` to get the position, but it didn't work.

```js
$('.scroll-block:first').addClass('is-current');
$(window).on('mouseover', function(event) {
  if ($('.scroll-block').hasClass('is-current')) {
    $('.scroll-block').removeClass('is-current');
    $(event.target).parents('.scroll-block:first').addClass('is-current');
  } else {
    $(event.target).parents('.scroll-block:first').addClass('is-current');
  };
});

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var position;
  $('.is-current').each(function() {
    position = $(this);
    console.log(scroll)
    $('html').animate({
      scrollTop: position.next().offset().top
    }, 800)
    console.log($(this).next().offset().top)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-block container" id="block1"></div>
<div class="scroll-block container" id="block2"></div>
<div class="scroll-block container" id="block3"></div>
<div class="scroll-block container" id="block4"></div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet to a [mcve]

Comment: Try `scrollTop: $('.is-current').next().position().top`

Comment: It runs .top is undefined. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.  you want to snap the next div to the top when scrolling?

Comment: Yep. I update my code use  ```.each``` to get the position. But when I scroll it goes back to the first div.

Comment: your code does nothing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

use CSS `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory` to "locking" the position of the viewport to specific elements on the page as the window.

[scroll-snap-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-snap-type/)